# Markers are not Perfect Circles?

Tags: matlab, aspect-ratio

I'm using Matlab to conduct some particle dynamics simulations, and I'm defining each particle as a circular marker.  Basically, each time I update my plot, I resize these markers based upon the plot scale; my plotting code for all of this can be found below:

```
%%Initial Plot at time t = 0 Along with Scaling in the Y-Direction
figure;
h=scatter(Pos(1,:),Pos(2,:),6,jet(length(Pos(1,:))),'filled','MarkerEdgeColor','k','linewidth',1);
hold on
axis ([0 dp 0 dp]*L*Scale)
currentunits = get(gca,'Units');
set(gca, 'Units', 'Points');
axpos = get(gca,'Position');
set(gca, 'Units', currentunits);
markerWidth = dp/diff(ylim)*axpos(4); % Calculate Marker width in points
set(h, 'SizeData', markerWidth^2)
```

Here's the odd problem I've encountered.  When I run my simulation, I have found that particles are not arranging as they should, accordng to a lot of literature on this.  Basically, I end up with gaps between the particles in the x-direction (y-direction is fine).
Initially, I thought there was some problem with my repulsive forces, but I went back and rearranged particles such that they would be touching (as an initial test), and I noticed that - although the parameters were correct - the plotted markers were not touching in the x-direction (again, the y-direction was fine).
It seems as though Matlab markers are not perfect circles?
Does anyone have any additional information on this or ideas how to resolve the fact that markers are behaving in this fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your desired behavior by calling `axis equal` before you set the axis limits.

---

While you set the axis *range* to equal values, your *aspect ratio* can be off. Therefore, the circular markers may not touch. Here's an example based on your approach (slightly modified for simplicity):

```
figure;

POINTS = [1 1;
          2 1;
          1 2];

h = plot(POINTS(:,1),POINTS(:,2),'o');

%axis equal

dp = 3;
axis ([0 dp 0 dp])

set(gca, 'Units', 'Points');
axpos = get(gca,'Position');
markerWidth = 1/(dp)*axpos(4);
set(h, 'markersize', markerWidth);
```

This produces the following simple plot:

[image: original aspect ratio]

I believe, this is what you experience. Now, if you uncomment the `axis equal` in the example above, you get this plot:

[image: equal aspect ratio]

---

You can also get the current aspect ratio by using [`daspect`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/daspect.html). With the original example here, you'll get `[1.5 1.5 1.0]` when calling `daspect` without any argument.
If you wanted a specific aspect ratio, you could call `daspect` after the plot like this, for example:

```
daspect([2 1 1])
```

This will give you this plot:

[image: different aspect ratio]

Note, that you always have to provide a factor for all three axis to `daspect` (even if, like here, there is no z-axis).
Setting `daspect([1 1 1])` is the same as `axis equal`.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the detailed explanation!   When I tried this out, it worked perfectly, but I want to look into it a bit further.  Either way, I find this property associated with matlab very odd.  I'll comment back after I do some initial testing associated with this tomorrow or Monday.

Comment: This worked perfectly and solved my problem (after a few tweaks to other areas of my program); thank you so much for the suggestion and great information!!

Comment: @Incognito: You are welcome. If you stick around and gain reputation, maybe you come back in time to upvote the answer ;-)